# Bash Script for Concatenating Broken Dashed Words

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, data-cleaning

I've scraped a large amount (10GB) of PDFs and converted them to text files, but due to the format of the original PDFs, there is an issue:

Many of the words which break across lines have a dash in them that artificially breaks up the word, like this:

[image]

You can see that this happened because the original PDFs files have breaks:

[image]

What would be the cleanest and fastest way to "join" every word instance that matches this pattern inside of a `.txt` file?

Perhaps some sort of Regex search, like for a `[a-z]\-\s \w` of some kind (word character followed by dash followed by space) would work?
Or would some sort of `sed` replacement work better?

Currently, I'm trying to get a sed regex to work, but I'm not sure how to translate this to use capture groups to replace the selected text:

`sed -n '\%\w\- [a-z]%p' Filename.txt`

My input text would look like this:

```
The dog rolled down the st- eep hill and pl- ayed outside.
```

And the output would be:

```
The dog rolled down the steep hill and played outside.
```

Ideally, the expression would also work for words split up by a newline, like this:

```
The rule which provided for the consid-
eration of the resolution, was agreed to earlier by a
```

To this:

```
The rule which provided for the consideration 
of the resolution, was agreed to earlier by a
```

Comment: Perhaps using 2 capturing groups and replace using those 2 groups only. `([a-z])-\r?\n(\w)` https://regex101.com/r/IoGA1x/1

Comment: This seems like it would work, how does one implement the capture replacements? (I've added my attempt above, FYI).

Comment: Just added the input/output text to the above question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's straightforward in sed:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '/-$/{N;s/-\n//;ba
}' -e 's/- //g' filename
```

This translates roughly as "if the line ends with a dash, read in the next line as well (so that you have a line with a carriage return in the middle) then excise the dash and carriage return, and loop back the beginning just in case this new line also ends with a dash. Then remove any instances of `-` ".

Comment: This is great! It meets the second use-case perfectly. How would you recommend adapting this to also fix the in-line break-ups, like the first sentence?

Comment: @HarryCramer: Sorry, I posted before you edited the question, and I didn't notice the internal breaks in the screenshot. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `gnu-awk` code:

```sh
cat file

The dog rolled down the st- eep hill and pl- ayed outside.
The rule which provided for the consid-
eration of the resolution, was agreed to earlier by a
```

Then use awk like this:

```sh
awk 'p != "" {
   w = $1
   $1 = ""
   sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, ORS)
   $0 = p w $0
   p = ""
}
{
   $0 = gensub(/([_[:alnum:]])-[[:blank:]]+([_[:alnum:]])/, "\\1\\2", "g")
}
/-$/ {
   p = $0
   sub(/-$/, "", p)
}
p == ""' file
```

```
The dog rolled down the steep hill and played outside.
The rule which provided for the consideration
of the resolution, was agreed to earlier by a
```

---

If you can consider `perl` then this may also work for you:

Then use:

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/(\w)-\h+(\w)/$1$2/g; s/(\w)-\R(\w+)\s+/$1$2\n/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply add backslash-parentheses (or use the `-r` or `-E` option if available to do away with the requirement to put backslashes before capturing parentheses) and recall the matched text with `\1` for the first capturing parenthesis, `\2` for the second, etc.

```sh
sed 's/\(\w\)\- \([a-z]\)/\1\2/g' Filename.txt
```

The `\w` escape is not standard `sed` but if it works for you, feel free to use it.  Otherwise, it is easy to replace with `[A-Za-z0-9_@]` or whatever else you want to call "word characters".

I'm guessing not all of the matches will be hyphenated words so perhaps run the result through a spelling checker or something to verify whether the result is an English word. (I would probably switch to a more capable scripting language like Python for that, though.)